# I wanted to close the dropdown that appears on touching(clicking) the toggle button.(mobile view)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Dropdown should be closed after touching on any  of the list items that are present in dropdown menu. Currently it only closes after touching on toggle button back, but it should be closed after anywhere I click on screen. It can be done using javascript and jquery. I don't know which div to target and after what code should I use. Can it be done using jquery effects?

Html code :

```css
.navbar-inverse {
  background: #E0FFFF;
  border: none;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: black;
  background: #13B1CD;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  background: #13B1CD;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav  > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #13B1CD;
  color: white;     
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu> li> a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: white;
  color:#13B1CD;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color:white;
  /* I have just used it to change the  regular toggle color */
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar :hover { /*Not working */
  background-color:white;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu> li> a:hover {   /*    This i haved used to change the hover of dropdown menu*/
  background:white;
  color:white;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    background: #333;
  }
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400i|Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Vendor Styles -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="vendor/themify/themify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="vendor/scrollbar/scrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="vendor/swiper/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="vendor/cubeportfolio/css/cubeportfolio.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <!-- Theme Styles -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/global/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon.png">



<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation" style="background-color:white;border:none;color:black;height:90px;">
    <div class="container" style="font-family:Century Gothic, sans-serif;  margin-top:18px;">
        <div class="box" style="padding-left:5px;height=50px;">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button style="background-color:#42C1D7" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <!-- data-target is used to target line 40 navbar-->
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <!--Toogle navigation  cannot be seen due to sr-only,it is only used tell users that this part is toggle navigation,only programmers it is usable-->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <!-- Writing this span tag three times to produce three lines in toggle button that is used in small screen-->
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="login.html" style="color:#1A237E"><img src="" height="85px;" width="100px;" style="margin-top:-30px;"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="color:black;">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                         aria-hidden="true"> </span><b> Home</b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#aboutus"><b>About Us</b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#products"><b>Products</b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services"><b>Services</b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#awards"><b>Awards</b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contacts"><b>Contacts</b></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#careers"><b>Careers</b></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the div ".navbar-collapse collapse". When the dropdown is open, a class called "show" is added and the div appears as ".navbar-collapse collapse show". Create a click event that removes that class "show"

```
$('.nav-item').click(function(){
    $('.collapse').removeClass('show');
});
```

Comment: I need to add class "in" ?

Comment: No, you need to remove that class. If the class "in" is present, the dropdown will be open. If you remove the class "in" the dropdown will close.

Comment: Bro do you have any example?How to create an event that removes class "in"?

Comment: I just updated my answer. It looks like the correct class is "show", not "in". My bad. I just got it to work in a Codepen.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ljyockey/pen/RjapJy It's literally just the two lines of code in the answer.

Comment: Bro I am currently working on  bootstrap 3.So can you show me using bootstrap 3?